# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS with .htaccess using two different CMS's

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two setups installed on my hosting, the first one is a php script to track shows and etc, is in the root folder, it contains a .htaccess file, the second one is a forum, installed in /forum/, it won't let me do anything with the forum folder unless I remove the first CMS from the root folder, so afther that It will allow me to acess to it, the thing is I don't know what is causing the redirects.

This is the .htaccess file located in the root folder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    ##
    ## You may need to uncomment (remove #) the following line for some hosting environments,
    ##
    # RewriteBase /

    ##
    ## Uncomment following lines to force HTTPS.
    ##
    # RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    # RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: There are no redirects in the code you posted. What URLs trigger the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS? What is the nature of the redirect? You say that's the `.htaccess` file from the root, but you also stated that you've removed the first CMS from the root folder? But not the `.htaccess` file? The `.htaccess` file you've posted rewrites all requests to a `/public` subdirectory, which presumably has another `.htaccess` file? So, the CMS is really located in the `/public` subdirectory, not the root?! But how are you able to access the forum if you are getting ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS?

Comment: Let's see.

The URL that triggers this would be located in /forum/, totally external of the purpose and use of the main CMS that is located in the root. The main CMS has a htaccess file that came with it during the installation. If I remove that CMS with that htaccess, I'm able to enter the forum, and adding it bacl It won't let me enter, it will trigger the redirect loop, so that's how I was able to enter the forum first, by removing the first cms that is causing this.

Comment: An update, just removing or renaming the htaccess file allows me to enter the forum, but the main site won't work, so I guess it is something related with the htaccess for sure. Also, putting the forum folder inside /public/ also works, without even removing the .htaccess.

And yes, there is another .htaccess file inside public, which contains more lines.

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently I found how to fix it here [[Solved] How to Fix Apache .htaccess redirect loop ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS Issue](https://www.transfermyvideofiles.com/solved-apache-htaccess-redirect-loop-error/) I created a new .htaccess inside the **/forum/** folder and added these lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://transfermyvideofiles.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

and now it's working. Also, if I change the RewriteCond HTTPS to on, it won't work, so the loop is getting caused by a bad HTTPS config.

Comment: If you added that rule to the "`.htaccess` file inside the `/forum/` folder" then it would _remove_ `/forum` from the start of the URL-path when redirecting from HTTP to HTTPS - which I'm sure is not the intention? "if I change the RewriteCond HTTPS to on" - Changing that _condition_ to `on` makes no sense (is that what you had previously?!) - this is not an indication of "a bad HTTPS config". Your HTTPS config would seem to be just fine. However, this and the linked article do nothing to resolve an existing redirect loop. There would seem to have been something else going on here.